# Rename a users in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have had an associate get married and while I have changed their name in all other systems I can't see a way to change the display name in Azure DevOps. They have a fair number or work assignments so I don't really want to delete and add them back. Is there a way to simply update their display name?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in profile settings [profile settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/set-your-preferences?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page).
One of the icons in the upper right corner opens the settings page.

Comment: That looks like a good solution but the options on the screen are grayed out for all users, including me as an admin.

Comment: I was able to get it changed going a bit deeper.  On the profile page, there is a link to Azure DevOps Profile Page that allowed a change.  We will call it the "joys of bad UX".